# Python overwrites list values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Im trying to parse some XML files.. but for some reason it overwrites the list values even tho I append to the list.

Code here:

```
def parseXML():
    xmlfiles = glob.glob('./*.xml')
    temp = {}

    for host in xmlfiles:
        tree = ET.parse(host)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for wizard in tree.findall('.'):
            for grandpa in wizard:
                for parent in grandpa:
                    if parent.get('addr') != None:
                        ip = parent.get('addr')
                        temp[ip] = {}
                    for child in parent:
                        if child.get('portid') != None:
                            for grandchild in child:
                                if grandchild.get('name') != None:
                                    name = grandchild.get('name')
                                    if child.get('portid') not in temp:
                                        temp[ip][name] = []
                                        temp[ip][name].append(child.get('portid'))
                                    else:
                                        print (temp + " else")


    print (temp)
```

expected outcome:

```
{'127.0.0.2': {'ssh': ['22'], 'http': ['80','8080']}, '127.0.0.1': {'ssh': ['22'], 'http': ['80','8080']}}
```

but Instead I get:

```
{'127.0.0.2': {'ssh': ['22'], 'http': ['8080']}, '127.0.0.1': {'ssh': ['22'], 'http': ['8080']}}
```

Comment: Your code is a bit difficult to parse without seeing the accompanying XML, but `if child.get('portid') not in temp` -- don't you want to check `temp[ip][name]`?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put your source XML. I'm sure the parsing of the file can be done more elegantly than with lots of nested if/else..

Comment: e.g. using xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp[ip][name] = []
temp[ip][name].append(child.get('portid'))
```

You're clearing your list before each append. Try moving that first line above the `if` block it's currently in.